# Listen keyboard input with only typescript

Tags: typescript, input, keyboard

So recently, i've been trying to create a typescript programm that runs in background to listen for any keyboard event.

As far as i've searched, i couldn't find documentation about it, so is it even possible ?

Only things, i found are :

- the addEventListener(), but it comes from the web api,and i want my script to run outside of a browser
- many npm packages that either work from a browser, or a Terminal

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: `TypeScript` is just a superset of `JavaScript`, so it doesn't provide any additional features for listening to hardware events; it must rely on `Node.js` or other runtime environments and their libs/deps... in other words, listening for keyboard events outside of a browser environment in TS requires a Node.js context with access to the appropriate system-level APIs

Comment: Like the comment above said, you definitely need to have a Node process that would stay alive and keep running your TS script in the background. If you *really* want to write that code in TS and have it run directly on your OS, then you need to check if Node even has the API hooks you need (like listening to OS keypresses). If yes, then it's possible to write a .bat/.sh script that starts up Node and makes it execute your program. That being said, it should be a million times easier to just write and run the same thing in a language that's natively closer to your OS, like C# or even Python.

Comment: Indeed, with your explanations i understand better the real problem behind that. I've found a package that seems to do the work for some Ubuntu versions, but it is indeed hell of a work compared to other languages like you said. This said, thanks for the details !